# Checking if cookie is set

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, session, razor

I am trying to render a toolbar at the top of a users screen if they are logged in, where they can access their account etc. If they are not logged in, it will display a form allowing them to log in. I'm not entirely sure how to do this using C# and Razor and keep hitting syntax and compilation errors.

My current form is as follows : I have one file, _siteLayout.cshtml. This stores the toolbar at the top of the screen. It checks the login form against the external database and if it is authenticated, creates gives the client a cookie. The form I essentially want is

```
if(user logged in)
   render account management page
else{
   render login page
}
```

Simple, but I am running into a lot of problems. Here is my code, removing the bulk, so far :

```
<body>
    @using System.Text;
    @using System.Net.Sockets;
   @{
        if(Request.Cookies["mpUsername"] == null){
        //if user is not logged in  
            //some authentication is ran, if passed, isValid is set to true    
                if (isValid) {
                    //login is valid, set cookie
                    HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies.Get("mpUsername");
                if(cookie == null) {
                    cookie = new HttpCookie("mpUsername");
                    cookie.Value = username;
                    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3);
                    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
                }
                } else {
                    //login invalid, prompt for pass again
                <text>Password incorrect, please try again</text>
                }
            } 
    }
  }//end of razor, HTML begins
    <html>
        <body>
        @{  //if cookie is set
            //if(Request.Cookies["mpUsername"] == null){   

        }
        <h2>ACCOUNT MANAGEMENT</h2>
        @{
          } else {//user not logged in, cookie not set
         }
        //login form
        </body>
    </html>
```

What is the best way of doing what I wish to do? In my actual code, the login form and account management pages are obviously far larger, so it's a little more confusing, hence why I removed these from the code above.

Comment: have you considered using FormsAuthentication ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.aspx

Comment: Yes, however I don't think that will support how I want authentication to run - I am verifying users login info against a remote server rather than a locally stored one.

Comment: I agree with Pauli - use the built in system.  It's very easy to miss something/leave a security hole open.

Comment: @SimonKiely - you can extend the basic forms auth classes to perform your actual verification the way you need, while still using the form authentication 'framework'.

Comment: @Paddy Thank you for that, I will certainly look into this. As an aside, does anyone know where I could find some examples of how to integrate this into my website? I assume once it is integrated, I will still be left with the problem I have above! :)

Comment: @SimonKiely how you authenticate is not really any of FormsAuthentication's business. All you have to do is call SetAuthCookie http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twk5762b.aspx if the users supplied credentials can be validated.

Comment: @Simon - it should be as simple as then checking if (Request.IsAuthenticated).  The forms auth is set up in your configuration and the user's authentication is checked before they hit your code.

Comment: This will help you learn about [Cookies in ASP.NET using C#](http://mindstick.com/Articles/c4e253f5-67dc-4211-8a1f-e29c17ce2943/?Cookies%20in%20ASP.NET).